# iphone - Xcode 3.2.3 error regarding deployment target

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an application that is supporting iOS 2.0.

The Base SDK is set to iPhone Device 4 and 
the iPhone OS Deployment Target is set to iPhone OS 2.0

My intention is to build it compatible with iPhone 3/3GS and 4
and iPod touch 2nd generation

This settings I have compile file, but when I upload it to iTunes Connect I see this error

**The binary you uploaded was invalid. Applications built for more than one architecture require a iPhone OS Deployment Target of 3.0 or later.**

How do I solve that?
thanks

====
*just a note: my Xcode 3.2.3 allows me compiling for 2.x because I copied the necessary files from older Xcodes to this newest one*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Deployment Target to 3.0, Apple doesn't support iOS 2 anymore.

If you want the app to be compatible with the 2nd gen iPod touch, that isn't a problem, as this device is perfectly capable of running iOS 3 and 4.

Comment: the existing customers can still use the version on their devices. they can not upgrade to a newer version (unless they upgrade the OS)

Comment: As I said in the edit, it'll work on iPod touches just fine. And even if it didn't, it would be Apple telling them to get lost, not you. And frankly, what reason is there to stay on iOS 2? iOS 4 isn't supported by all devices (no iOS 4 for 1st gen iPhone and iPod touch), but iOS 3 is.

Comment: Just tell your customers as it is: Apple has decided to cut support for iOS2. I think you customers will bear with you as the matter is rather out of your hands. I think you have pursued the matter as far as you can without distributing the app directly to the unfortunate customers ad-hoc.