# Applications built for more than one architecture require an iOS Deployment Target of 3.0 or later. STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90081

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

## Preface

I want to start this question for various solutions to this problem, **in general**.

There are lots of questions on this topic. Most are not duplicates. However, they all only apply to particular libraries or defects. So it felt wrong to post my answer to one of these questions.

### The specific subcategories of existing questions

**Firebase**

- [Error when distributing app through Xcode to App Store Connect - requires iOS Deployment Target of 3.0 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507609/error-when-distributing-app-through-xcode-to-app-store-connect-requires-ios-de)

**Flutter**

These 2 are probably duplicates:

- [ERROR ITMS-90208: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle <your.app> does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518765/error-itms-90208-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-your-app-does-not-support-the-mi)
- [Uploading flutter app to AppStore gives App.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637731/uploading-flutter-app-to-appstore-gives-app-framework-does-not-support-the-minim)

**Xamarin**

- [How to fix app does not support minimum version specified error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659164/how-to-fix-app-does-not-support-minimum-version-specified-error)

**Xcode 10**

These 3 are probably duplicates:

- [Invalid architectures Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427687/invalid-architectures-xcode-10)
- [Xcode 10 GM - Invalid Binary Architecture when submitting to App Store Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304108/xcode-10-gm-invalid-binary-architecture-when-submitting-to-app-store-connect)
- [While uploading to App Store the upload failed ERROR ITMS-90081](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588843/while-uploading-to-app-store-the-upload-failed-error-itms-90081)

**Too Old/Irrelevant**

- [iphone - Xcode 3.2.3 error regarding deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163621/iphone-xcode-3-2-3-error-regarding-deployment-target)

## The Question

I uploaded my app to Apple, and it was rejected. The reason Apple gave for the rejection was this error message:

> This bundle is invalid. Applications built for more than one architecture require an iOS Deployment Target of 3.0 or later. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90081

How do I solve this?

I will post my solution below, but there are probably several other cases that lead to this same result. And these general cases are often not related to the specific cases listed above.

Answer (score 0):

So many internet search results told me that the reason for this error was `MinimumOSVersion` was missing from the `Info.plist` of my XC framework, and the way to control that key in `Info.plist` was thru Xcode build setting `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`. That information was misleading. XC Frameworks are valid without `MinimumOSVersion` in `Info.plist`.

In my case, the root case of the problem was that I had inadvertently created what Apple calls an umbrella framework.

Thru process of elimination we had narrowed down the culprit library to `A.xcframework`.  `A.xcframework` was a pre-compiled framework that I built. `A.xcframework` was used in `B.xcframework`, and `B.xcframework` was compiled and used in `C.app`. It was `C.app` that was rejected by Apple.

To fix things, I did the following.

In Xcode, in `B.xcframework`, in the `B` target, *General* tab, *Frameworks and Libraries* section, I have `A.xcframework` listed. Under the *Embed* column, I changed its value to *Do Not Embed*.

I rebuilt `B.xcframework` and `C.app`, and the upload of that archive was accepted by Apple. No other change was necessary.

I could see the difference in the archive/IPA. In the rejected version, `A.framework` was listed. In the accepted version, `A.framework` was not there. This is because the *Do Not Embed* setting on it in `B.xcframework` meant that it was statically linked into `B`.